# Java 7u17 - Stop Java from going to website for update

Tags: java

Because of a critical LOB java app that won't run on a version of java later than 7u17, we're stuck with that version (for now). Occasionally, when a user starts the LOB app, Windows will prompt the user to block java (because it's outdated), update java, or defer the question until later (and allow java to run). Unfortunately, the caliber of user we have is ... less than I'd like, and our training is deficient when it comes to computers (and not under my control). As a result, we have frequent calls to the Help Desk because the user can't run the LOB app, because instead of java running, they get directed to the java download site - and they're not allowed to install software.

Up to now, we've been simply deleting the user's profile on the affected workstation, which clears whatever is set that automatically redirects the browser instead of running java. This seems... excessive. Is there a registry setting, or other "tweakable" data, that can be modified or deleted to "undo" this automatic redirection?

Comment: Set up an [autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) script that you can push out to every machine and just watches for the "Run Java..." window and presses the correct button before the user can?

Comment: @Mokubai - Not an option in this case, something like that would require vetting autohotkey as safe, and then putting a change request through. That involves Development and Information Security, as well as User Support, and would take months. I'm looking for a fix that I can use ten minutes ago to "clean up" the mess that the user makes by answering wrong - we've got a CR in progress to replace the LOB app entirely, but that's still down the road a piece.